# Redirect from index.html to its directory using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, directory-index

For each page of my website, it is named `index.html` and stored inside a folder of the name of the page.

- `example.com/` serves `example.com/index.html`
- `example.com/about/` serves `example.com/about/index.html`
- `example.com/work/` serves `example.com/work/index.html`

While all the links on my site are of the format `example.com/folder/`, how can I redirect any pages ending with `index.html` to the parent directory, as that is my preference?

So redirect `example.com/index.html` to `example.com/`
and `example.com/work/index.html` to `example.com/work/`

What do I need in a `.htaccess` file to 301 redirect as intended above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file. In its simplest form this would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "index.html"
RewriteRule (.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The regex `(.*)index\.html$` matches any URL-path that ends with `index.html` and captures the part of the URL-path before `index.html`.

The `$1` backreference contains the captured URL-path before the `index.html`. This would be *empty* in the case of `example.com/index.html` or `about/` in the case of `example.com/about/index.html`.

HOWEVER, the above will fail if you are also serving files that *end* with `index.html`, eg. `/something/foo_index.html`, as it will redirect to `/something/foo_`. If this is the case then you would need to change the regex in the above `RewriteRule` to something like `^(|.+/)index\.html$` instead. For example:

```
# Remove "index.html" (whole path segment only)
RewriteRule ^(|.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will then match `/index.html` and `/something/index.html`, but not `/something/foo_index.html`.

`^(|.+/)` matches either *nothing* (ie. the document root) or *something* followed by a slash (ie. a subdirectory).

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect in order to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure everything is working OK.

---

<sup>*Additional:*</sup>

#### Avoid redirect loop if rewriting to `index.html` (front-controller pattern)

The above is not sufficient if you are using a front-controller pattern to internally rewrite requests to `index.html` (not the case here), since the above would also redirect the rewritten request to `index.html` and trigger a redirect loop.

In this case you would need to add an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that ensures that only direct requests (by the user) are redirected and not rewritten requests by your script/directives.

You can do this by either checking against `THE_REQUEST` (which contains the first line of the request headers and does not change when the request is rewritten) OR the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable (which is *empty* on the initial request and set to "200" - as in 200 OK HTTP response - after the first successful rewrite).

For example:

```
# Remove "index.html" on direct requests only
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I thought that rewrite rule would redirect requests where the index.html is implicit .  I was thinking you'd have to match against the request URI environment variable instead.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I used to think that as well (a conflict with mod_dir/ `DirectoryIndex`) and I've seen this suggested in older articles. However, on Apache 2.2+ mod_rewrite executes before mod_dir - there is no conflict AFAICT. So, maybe this was a problem with Apache 1.3? Not sure. However, it is a problem if you try to use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` (which executes later). OR if you are rewriting requests to `index.html` (a front-controller pattern) - in which case you would indeed need additional checks to avoid a redirect loop.

Comment: _Aside:_ "match against the request URI var instead" - The `REQUEST_URI` server variable would have the same problem (as the `RewriteRule` _pattern_). You would need to use either `THE_REQUEST` or the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var. (If this was a problem.) @StephenOstermiller

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I knew I could count on you to have a good understanding of the details. I don't even try to answer questions like this anymore. I just wait until you jump in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate you explaining each part as while I have an overview of how it works, that helps me understand what's going on